# How to request OK to communicate by email (only)? Without coding

Tags: civicontribute

In the 'Manage Contribution Payment' screen we want to simply ask the donor if they are happy to be contacted by email - a simple Yes/No option in a profile. It doesn't seem possible to do this using the standard fields - 'Communication Preferences' brings up all the communications options. Is there any way to just expose the email field as a preference? I can do this with a custom field, but it would be better to set the actual email preference field.  I've a feeling this must be possible, and have a strong preference to avoid any coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the [optinfields extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/optinfields) do what you want?

Comment: It sounds ideal, I'll check it out

Comment: Looks good, thanks for such a quick answer.